# How to do customized template design using mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to include customized card design feature in my MVC application.We need the feature like MS paint.I want to do insert picture, shapes and text. Also I need to format the text. How do I proceed? Is there any tools available to include this feature in my MVC application ?

Comment: javascript canvas

Comment: Split your ptoblem to subproblems and try to look for solutions separately